# Python corrupts pdf after download from file

Tags: python, django, pdf

Somehow python corrupts my pdf file when i download the file as an attachment. I use the following code (and tried multiple variations) to download the file:

```
def print_pdf(request):

    filename = 'real.pdf' 

    response = HttpResponse(file(filename).read())
    response['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
    response['Content-disposition'] = 'attachment'

    return response
```

The original file is 108KB, the result is about 100bytes. Any idea what i am missing / doing wrong? If i change the filename is says it can not find the file, so it seems python has access to the local stored file.

Comment: I am not familiar with `file()` method as it might be a django thing - shouldn't you use `HttpResponse(open(filename).read())`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to open your file in binary mode.

```
pdf = open(filename, 'rb')
response = HttpResponse(pdf.read())
```

Note though that you shouldn't rely be serving media files like this: that's the job of your asset server.

Comment: Great, this almost worked. I had to change your code to open(filename, 'rb') to get it to work. If you edit the answer ill accept.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{filename}"'.format(filename=filename)
response['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
response.write(open(filename).read())
return response
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this however resulted in the same error. Also for django2.7 mimetype seems to be no longer valid. I used content_type instead.